# Update Haskell Package on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal, cabal-install

How do you update a pre-installed Haskell package (for example, the System.Directory package) on Windows? I've tried simply telling cabal to install it but it encountered an error while doing so.

```
The package has a '.configure' script. This requires a Unix compatibility toolchain such 
as MinGW+MSYS or Cygwin.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
directory-1.2.6.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I presume there is an easy way of doing this within cabal. Failing this, where do the various files in the .tar.gz available off Hackage for a pre-installed package go? Thanks in advance.

Comment: no there is no easy way using cabal - basically you do what you are told and get a Msys2 ... or you grab `stack` (which will get it for you)

Comment: I think they're only untared temporarily. You can use `cabal unpack` to get a local unpacked copy in your current directory. Note that updating the global Cabal package database is usually a bad idea.

Comment: So to put it more generally: what is the _recommended_ way of updating a given package?

Comment: @ENPM don't - use sandboxes or better stack to handle this for you (it will not update the package as in removing the old one) - but on windows the *sane* option right now is really stack - if you don't run into stupid restrictions with the length of paths it can handle almost anything you throw at it

Comment: @Carsten Alright so. Installing stack now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of ghc and the haskell platform ship with an msys distro. Adding a few lines (in the instructions) to the cabal config file allows `cabal` to take advantage of this, in after which you can build packages with custom configure scrips (such as `network` or `old-time`) just fine.